# CSS div (absolute within relative)

Tags: html, css

How i can make 2 different divs elements A and B what they are included on a div element C .

A and B to start from the same corner from top left, i try to change A and B to position absolute and working but i need A to keep it via position relative. the code can be found here https://jsfiddle.net/bms1upkn/2/

Html

```
<div class="c">
  <div class="a">
  </div>
  <div class="b">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="c">
  <div class="a">
  </div>
  <div class="b">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="c">
  <div class="a">
  </div>
  <div class="b">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="c">
  <div class="a">
  </div>
  <div class="b">
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.data {
  width: 100%;
}
.c {
  height: 200px;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.a {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

.b {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Hi. what exactly do you want to acieve. is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/bms1upkn/3/

Comment: @Matei, can you more elaborate your question or provide a image file what exactly you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want? Your description is difficult to comprehend.

https://jsfiddle.net/bms1upkn/4/

CSS:

```
.data {
  width: 100%;
}
.c {
  height: 200px;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position:relative;
}
.a {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

.b {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I success to find the issue following this , thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
.data {
  width: 100%;
}
.c {
  height: 200px;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position:relative; //new
}
.a {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

.b {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  left:0px; //new
  top:0px; //new
}
```